# NoReverseMatch at

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hola me podrían ayudar con este error:

```
Reverse for 'pedido_sub' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id_pedido': 53, 'cod_experto': 'AA-0002'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['solicitar/aprobar/(?P<id_pedido>\\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\\d+)$']
```

Esta es la url:

```
url(r'^aprobar/(?P<id_pedido>\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\d+)$', Pedidoapp.views.pedido_sub, name="pedido_sub"),
```

Y este el botón en index donde marca en rojo el error:

```
<a href="{% url "usuario:pedido_sub" id_pedido=ped.id cod_experto=ped.articulo.cod_experto %}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Aprobar" method="GET" onClick="location.reload();" />Aprobar</a>
```

Por favor espero su ayuda para este caso, gracias de ante mano!

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def pedido_sub(request, id_pedido, cod_experto):
    art = Articulo.objects.get(id=cod_experto)
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pedido.estado = 'entregado'
        pedido.save()
        pedido.fecha_entrega = datetime.now()
        pedido.save()
        art.stock = pedido.cantidad - art.stock
        art.save()
        return redirect('usuario:home')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'pedido':pedido})
```

Comment: Necesitas añadir el código que tiene el botón, de nada nos sirve el texto que tiene.

Comment: def pedido_sub(request, id_pedido, cod_experto):
    art = Articulo.objects.get(id=cod_experto)
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pedido.estado = 'entregado'
        pedido.save()
        pedido.fecha_entrega = datetime.now()
        pedido.save()
        art.stock = pedido.cantidad - art.stock
        art.save()
        return redirect('usuario:home')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'pedido':pedido})

Comment: Cuando escribas una pregunta: 1. Utiliza títulos **que describan el problema**. 2. Pon en tu pregunta **qué quieres hacer**.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que le estás pasando argumentos con nombre a tu url, cuando tu url está pidiendo argumentos posicionales, en el botón probablemente tengas algo como:

```
<a href="{% url pedido_sub id_pedido=obj.pedido cod_experto=obj.experto %}">
```

Y tendrías que cambiarlo a:

```
<a href="{% url pedido_sub obj.pedido obj.experto %}">
```

Luego tienes que asegurarte que tu vista también acepte parámetros posicionales y no nombrados.

Comment: estimado gracias por al respuesta, este el def de views.py :                                                 def pedido_sub(request, id_pedido, cod_experto):
    art = Articulo.objects.get(id=cod_experto)
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pedido.estado = 'entregado'
        pedido.save()
        pedido.fecha_entrega = datetime.now()
        pedido.save()
        art.stock = pedido.cantidad - art.stock
        art.save()
        return redirect('usuario:home')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'pedido':pedido})

Comment: y si así era como tenia el boton, lo cambie según lo sugiere, ahora bien como aceptaría en al vista los parámetros que comenta?

Comment: Así debería aceptarte los parametros, ¿te está fallando?